# yocto pyro 2.3 depended package build issue

Tags: yocto

I am configuring one  package "X" that is depended on other  package "Y".

the "Y" package is successfully build and I am able to find it into the below path.

tmp/work/cortexa8hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/"Y"/0.1.0-r1/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin

As per my understanding if the package "X" is depended on the package "Y" then all the components of the package "Y" should be copied into the path "recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin" of the package "X".

But I am not able to find the depended package "Y" into the recipe-sysroot-native of the Package "X".

If my understanding is false let me know the correct way to do this. As I am not able to find the package "Y" into the dir "recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin" of package "X"

thanks

Amit G.

Comment: Is the package you're concerned with a native or target package? If it's a target package you're looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

For a standard Y package, you have to add the following in X recipe to get Y into recipe-sysroot-native:

```
DEPENDS = "Y-native"
```

You have to be sure that "Y" recipe can be used as a native recipe, it must contains

`BBCLASSEXTEND = "native` (or `inherit native`)

Comment: Thanks It is working.Also you need to add BBCLASSEXTEND = "native" in the bb file of Y.

Comment: Glad it worked, and thanks for BBCLASSEXTEND precision, I added it in answer.